# Removing array elements that match with arguments and returning a new array

Tags: javascript, arrays, for-loop, foreach

I am using the forEach() on the array that is passed through. The function I am passing into forEach() is if the element of `arrays` does not match with one of the arguments given, then push it into the `newArray`.

However, I keep getting a blank array, when I want to see `newArray = [1, 2]`.

I am thinking there is something wrong with my if statement, but I really don't see what the problem is. I can't seem to put a finger on the issue.

```
const removeFromArray = function(arrays, ...args) {
    const newArray = [];
    
    for (const arg of args) {
        if (arrays.forEach((element) => element !== arg))
        newArray.push(element);        
    }
    return newArray;
}

removeFromArray([1,2,3], 3);
```

Comment: [`Array.prototype.filter()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) exists.

Comment: `array.forEach()` doesn't return anything.

Comment: don't do this kind of code, use `Array.filter()` method

Comment: Not sure exactly what your goal is here but if `Array.filter()` isn't what you're looking for also check out `Array.includes()`

Comment: Thanks all for the suggestions. I am misunderstanding forEach(). Will reread the docs.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I remove a specific item from an array in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5767325/how-can-i-remove-a-specific-item-from-an-array-in-javascript)

Comment: @wyck That is a good resource! For my question, I wanted to know why I am wrong so I can dash or revise my understanding. Thanks for your help.

Comment: weird this was closed.

Comment: Also the `args` parameter was presented as `...args` so presumably that means it's intended to work such that you can remove all the items that were provided as arguments.  e.g. `removeFromArray([1, 2, 3, 4], 1, 3)` I expect should return `[2, 4]`.  If so, the technique should be `array.filter(item => !args.includes(item))`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will assume that you are doing this for a learning experience.  As others have said, filter is what you should be using.  With that said you had a couple errors in your code.

1. You did if(array.forEach... which can not be evaluated as its a iterator and is not truthy
2. You needed to push the element inside the forEach, not outside if it

```js
const removeFromArray = function(arrays, ...args) {
    const newArray = [];
    
    for (const arg of args) {
        arrays.forEach(element => {
           if(element !== arg){
               newArray.push(element);               
           }
        })
    }
    return newArray;
}

console.log(removeFromArray([1,2,3], 3));
```

Comment: oops, this is backwards logic.  The expected result is `[1, 2]` you meant `element !== arg`

Comment: Thanks! I am self-studying the odin project. it's been rough. 

In my original code, I did if (arrays.forEach...), but I can't seem to grasp why that is wrong. To me it reads like this: 

 if an element in the `arrays` does not equal an `arg` THEN push it in. But this is not how it's being interpreted?

Comment: @MCodet  arrays.forEach is a iterator, like a program flow.  doing if(array.forEach wouldnt be that unlike doing if(switch....  or even if(  if (  .   Now, you might do something like if(array.length......  .  Put another way whatever is in the if(...) needs to be something that can be evaluated.  forEach can not be evaluated for truthyness

Comment: @terpinmd My wow. That makes sense. Thank you so much. I suppose I will have to be mindful of whether methods can be evaluated for a Boolean or perform some other purpose that I hope to learn. Thanks again!

Comment: @MCodet happy coding!  If the answer and comments are suitable pls consider accepting this as the answer :)

Comment: @terpinmd sorry, I am a bit late to the reply, but I accepted your answer. Got to get used to accepting answers :)  Not sure why someone closed the question, but I'll try to formulate better questions next time if mine was too simple. Thanks, again for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Try using `Array.filter()` method

```
const removeFromArray = function(arrays, args) {
    return arrays.filter(ele => ele !== args)
}

removeFromArray([1,2,3], 3);
```

Comment: read carefuly the question this is `function(arrays, ...args)` , not `function(arrays, args)`